# How to delay input submit button in a few seconds before submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a modal that has list of purposes that the student will choose and after clicking confirm it automatically redirect the the success message page,
Is there a way to delay the  input type submit i want to display to the student 
what he choose in few seconds and redirect to success message.

Here is the modal form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered  modal-notify modal-info modal-sm"role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header  d-flex justify-content-center">
                 <p class="heading">Your Purpose ?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
           <form method="post" action="index111.php">

<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="purpose1" name="purpose" value="Assignment">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="purpose1">Assignment</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="purpose2" name="purpose" value="Reading">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="purpose2">Reading</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="purpose3" name="purpose" value="Research">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="purpose3">Research</label>
</div>  
            <div class="modal-footer flex-center">  

                <button type="submit"  name="submit02" id="modal_button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code in index111.php:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 include_once ('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit02']))
{
$time=date("H:i:s");
$purpose = $_POST['purpose'];
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from student_att  order by number DESC limit 1");
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                  $rfid=$row['rfid_num'];
        $InsertSql = "Update student_att set purpose = '$purpose' , timein = '$time' where rfid_num='$rfid' order by number DESC limit 1";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSql);  
            header("location:valid.php");
             }
    }     
?>
```

The valid.php is the success message, hope you can help me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a jquery function like so:

```js
$('#myform').submit(function(event) {
  var form = this;
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.modal-body').append('You chose an option: '+$("input[name=purpose]:checked").val());
  setTimeout( function () {
        form.submit();
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered  modal-notify modal-info modal-sm"role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header  d-flex justify-content-center">
                 <p class="heading">Your Purpose ?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
           <form method="post" action="index111.php" id="myform">

<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="purpose1" name="purpose" value="Assignment">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="purpose1">Assignment</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="purpose2" name="purpose" value="Reading">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="purpose2">Reading</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="purpose3" name="purpose" value="Research">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="purpose3">Research</label>
</div>  
            <div class="modal-footer flex-center">  

                <button type="submit"  name="submit02" id="modal_button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```